# MySql inner join with order by

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, inner-join

i have two tables USERS and VOTES;

i do inner join with two tables with below code;

```
select *, count(*) as people_count from users inner join votes 

on users.id=votes.user_id and votes.choise_id=1 

group by users.country, votes.choise_id 

order by votes.time desc;
```

[image: USERS AND VOTES TABLES]

i get bellow result

i want last comment that Erric's, not Tom's

[image: result]

you can run the code from below link

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69cc95/3

thanks for your help

Best Regards

Comment: You are grouping by `country` so you only get one row for each country.  If you want all the rows, remove the `group by`.

Comment: i just want only one row with lates comment like below

eric  -- us -- 2 --- 1 --- im agree with tom --- date ---- 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find a sollution 
but i m not sure if it is fast enough

```
select * , count(*) as people_count from 

(select * from votes v 
 inner join users u
 on v.user_id=u.id
 where v.choise_id=1
 order by v.time desc
) t

group by t.country
```

you can examine from below link

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69cc95/40

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row with the latest value, then you should use `not exists` rather than `group by`:

```
select *,
       (select count(*) from votes where v.choise_id = 1) as people_count
from users u inner join 
     votes v
     on u.id = v.user_id and v.choise_id = 1 
where not exists (select 1
                  from users u2 join
                       votes v2
                       u2.id = v2.user_id
                  where u2.country = u.country and
                        v2.choise_id = v.choise_id and
                        v2.time > v.time
                 );
```

Comment: it gives people_count=1, i also need to learn how many votes are there.

You can see your code here   http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69cc95/22

Comment: thanks for your effor. i think i find some sollution and share it